# A class extends a superclass called Object

Tags: java, inheritance, object, subclass, superclass

If a class `Puppy` inherits `Object` by default, if I want my `Puppy` class to extend a superclass `Dog`, does the `Puppy` still extends `Object` at all times?

I'm not too sure about this but I think the `Puppy` still extends `Object` all times, seeing as Eclipse provides me the methods of the `Object` Class.

Answer (score 1):

Puppy will inherit Dog, which will inherit Object. The answer to your question is yes. *All* classes inherit Object at some point in their class hierarchy. This is why your brand new *NewClass* will have *toString()*, *hashCode()* and other functions you find in Object.

Answer (score 0):

No, Puppy extends Dog and Dog extends Object.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Dog` also extends the default class (being `Object`), it will be true that `Puppy` extends `Dog` that extends `Object`.

And this means that `Puppy` extends `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

`Puppy` `extends` `Dog` and `Dog` `extends` `Object` so you get all the `methods` from `Object` in the `Puppy`.

Answer (score 0):

Think in terms of **inheritance hierarchy**.

If you go up the hierarcy, the topmost class (`Dog`) in the hierarchy by default extends the `Object`.

And a subclass always inherits all the inheritable members of it's superclass no matter even if they were in turn inherited by the superclass from some other superclass of it's own.

So, even though the `Puppy` is not extending the `Object` directly, it's inheriting the members of `Object` through that hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it does.